# Trying to automate a process in console application

Tags: winapi, console-application

I am trying to get my console application to simulate dragging and dropping a file, so far I have had no luck.

The system throws a win32 exception stating it cannot find the file, since I know that is not really the problem I was hoping someone could shed some light on what might be causing this behavior.

I suspect it might be DEP. I can drag and drop the file and the process runs as expected, but I need to automate this.

I have created a filewatcher and am right now trying to figure out how to get the code to work, prior to making it a windows service.

But right now I am really stuck on this win32 error.

```
     public class Watcher
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();


        // If a directory is not specified, exit program.
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {

           // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");

            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                   | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch jpg files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.jpg";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        Process.Start(e.FullPath + "c:\\demo\\kr-pano\\mpr.bat");

}
```

Visit the link to see the full win32 exception details. 
[Win32Exception](http://southfloridacoder.com/blog/2017/11/14/win32-exception/)

Comment: Add the exception  text completely to the question. Don't use external links.

Comment: I was afraid the formatting gods would smite me. I managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue is being caused because the filesystemwatcher is single threaded, and when I try to launch my new process it stops the old one from running. All I needed to do was stub out a new runpano function and call it from my code, its working now.